# Is there any GoogleGroup API to fetch data from Google Groups

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to Access Google group information from asp.net using C#. Please suggest for any avaliable API or documentations to refer.

Thanks 
Karteek.

Comment: Oh, I so wish there was! Maybe someone knows. +1

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a API for groups, but groups do have feeds and you can use the feed API.

Here is the FAQ about the group feed: http://groups.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=46384

Here is some info on the feeds ajax API: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/

And finally here is the .Net guide: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/client-cs.html

Years ago I wrote a simple library in C# to access google's gmail feeds, it may still apply. If you want to have a look you can find it here: [Gmail Tools Blog Entry](http://ryanscook.com/adminsBlog/2005/05/c-net-gmail-tools_26.html)